# Ruby use stdin twice

Tags: ruby, git, bash, gitlab

In continuum to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/716765/gitlab-automatic-deploy/)

I have a git hook written in ruby. I want to use the input from stdin twice. I have two of the same type (post-receive) of git hooks, and want them both executed as if they were called by git. The first hook is in ruby, and is the default hook for gitlab git. Second will be a bash script that I have yet to create. I would prefer to leave the first ruby hook as untouched as possible, although a few added lines will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that stdin, in this case, is a pipe.<sup>†</sup>

You can't rewind a pipe. What you need to do is to [copy](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-copy_stream) the pipe's data into a regular file, then use that file as stdin for the two processes you're calling.

(You can also copy into a memory buffer, and then use a pipe to send the contents to the two processes.)

---

Update: here's a simple Ruby script that checks whether stdin is a regular file, and if not, it creates a temp file and copies stdin to it first, then rebinds stdin to the temp file. Then it runs each argument as a command:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'tempfile'

unless File.file?($stdin)
  Tempfile.open('stdin') do |temp|
    IO.copy_stream($stdin, temp)
    $stdin.reopen(temp)
    temp.unlink
  end
end

ARGV.each do |arg|
  $stdin.rewind
  system arg
end
```

Example usage (assuming the file is named `multiwrite` in the current directory):

```
$ echo foo | ./multiwrite cat 'tr a-z A-Z' 'tr a-z n-za-m'
foo
FOO
sbb
```

<sup>†</sup> If it's a regular file, then the solution is easy: call the first process, then rewind, then call the second process.

Comment: It is a git hook, pretty sure that is a pipe? How can I actually do the copy stdin to a file in a script?

Comment: Is a git hook a pipe?

Comment: I don't know, but my script makes it so that it works correctly whether it's a pipe or not.

Comment: So all I have to do is remove that last stanza, call my first script, and `$stdin.rewind`, then call the second script?

Comment: Pretty much. Test it and see! If it doesn't work, link a Gist here and I can try to debug.